# How can get a correct type in re-map to array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to get related type by key. I created a function pass key to get related types. But I think It is so dirty approach. Anyone can give me suggestions to improve this approach? Thank you.

```
type IUser = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const User = {
  name: 'test',
  age: 12
}

Object.keys(User).reduce<IUser>((prev, key) => {
    function getValue<T extends Object, S extends keyof T>(p: T, k: S) {
      return p[k];
    }

    switch (key as keyof IUser) {
      case 'name': {
        const value = getValue<IUser, 'name'>(User, 'name'); 
        // this for get related type, e.g. in this case for get string type
        return { ...prev, name: value };
      }

  }, {age: 0, name: ""});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `switch` statement here.

```js
type IUser = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const User = {
    name: 'test',
    age: 12
}

const getValue = <
    Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>,
    Prop extends keyof Obj
>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop) => obj[prop];

const update = (prev: IUser, key: keyof IUser) =>
    ({ ...prev, [key]: getValue(User, key) })

const INITIAL = { age: 0, name: "" }

const result =
    (Object.keys(User) as Array<keyof IUser>)
        .reduce(update, INITIAL);
```

[Playground](http://tsplay.dev/Na082w)

Since you already iterate through `User` keys, you can just apply generic `update` function to each key